# "sentiment analysis" using "sst2" dataset (Classification)

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to fine-tune "distilbert-base-uncased" model using huggingface libraries, but I run to this error:

```
IndexError: Target -1 is out of bounds.
```

after loading my dataset (sst2) using huggingface data set and tokenizing them:

```
small_train_dataset = encoded_dataset["train"].shuffle(seed=42).select(range(1000))
small_eval_dataset = encoded_dataset["test"].shuffle(seed=42).select(range(1000))
full_train_dataset = encoded_dataset["train"]
full_eval_dataset = encoded_dataset["test"]
```

```
# Define the training parameters

metric_name = "accuracy"
model_name = model_checkpoint.split("/")[-1]
weight_decay = 0.01
lr = 2e-5
batch_size = 16
num_train_epochs = 5
```

```
import numpy as np

# Define a function to evaluate the model

def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    logits, labels = eval_pred
    predictions = np.argmax(logits, axis=-1)
    return metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels)
```

```
# Fine-tune the model

args = TrainingArguments(
    f"{model_name}-finetuned-{task}",
    evaluation_strategy = "steps",             
    eval_steps=10,
    save_strategy = "steps",                   
    learning_rate = lr,                   
    per_device_train_batch_size = batch_size,     
    per_device_eval_batch_size = batch_size,      
    num_train_epochs = num_train_epochs,                
    weight_decay = weight_decay,                    
    load_best_model_at_end = True,          
    metric_for_best_model = metric_name,          
    push_to_hub = False,                    
)
```

```
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=args,
    train_dataset = small_train_dataset,           
    eval_dataset = small_eval_dataset,            
    tokenizer = tokenizer,               
    compute_metrics = compute_metrics         
)
```

```
trainer.train()
```

I tried changing the metric, but it didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was with the dataset, I used encoded_dataset["test"] for validation, which unlike its name consists of unsupervised data all with labels -1. after changing that to encoded_dataset["validation"] problem was fixed.

Comment: There was no way anyone would have guessed this from the info you have provided, and the answer is highly unlikely to be of help for anyone else in the future. I kindly suggest you delete the thread now.